# Extracting a C# Embedded Resource in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I'm trying to extract an embedded resource from a .exe file. I can easily get the embedded resource out from C# code like so:

```
string changeLog;

/* Get the changelog embedded resource */
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("SIPBandVoIPClient.CHANGELOG.md"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    changeLog = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

However, now I'm trying to get the embedded resource out from JavaScript/nodeJS.

I tried just 'grepping' for some of the text that I knew was in the file, but I couldn't find it. Perhaps it's base64 encoded?

Edit: I tried embedding the resource in a different way - by using the properties section in Visual Studio, instead of adding the file to the project, and marking it as a resource.

Now, I can access it like so:

```
string changeLog = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resources.CHANGELOG);
```

Furthermore, I can find the text verbatim in the .exe. Before the text, there is some (binary?) data like this:

[image]

(Apologies for the screenshot, the text itself would not render nicely due to non printable characters, I assume)

I'm wondering if there's a way to convert this from whatever binary rubbish it is to a tag I can use to search the .exe. I could of course search for the "All notable changes to this project..." and back up a bit, but it seems a bit error prone. Would also be handy to know where to stop accurately.

I did consider using the node-ffi module, and hooking up to the Windows Api functions, however, this would be Windows only, and I think I need Linux support.